# Where is settings.json for powershell configuration in Windows Terminal?

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Windows 10, having spent a lot of time on Mac OS X and some on Ubuntu, and I've read a lot about the types of things that are good to put in the `settings.json` file for my [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-7), but I can't seem to find anything that tells me *where* this file resides.

For example, the "Set up Powerline in PowerShell" section in [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/powerline-setup) tells you to edit your `settings.json` file (specifically in the subsection titled "[Set Cascadia Code PL as fontFace in settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/powerline-setup#set-cascadia-code-pl-as-fontface-in-settings)"), and points you to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-settings) telling you about the layout of this file, but it doesn't seem to tell you where to find it!

In case the subsection gets changed, this is the first two paragraphs of that section:

> To set the Cascadia Code PL font for use with PowerLine (after
> downloading, unzipping, and installing on your system), you will need
> to open your profile settings in your settings.json file by selecting
> Settings (Ctrl+,) from your Windows Terminal drop-down menu.
>
> Once your settings.json file opens, find the Windows PowerShell
> profile and add: "fontFace": "Cascadia Code PL" to designate Cascadia
> Code PL as the font. This will provide those nice Cascadia Code
> Powerline glyphs. You should notice the change in your terminal as
> soon as you select Save in your editor.

Where is the `settings.json` file?

Comment: why do you think there is a `Settings.JSON` file for powershell? i've never seen such. settings for PoSh are usually in the `$Profile` files that are/is being run. take a look at `Get-Help about_Profiles`.

Comment: @BenHocking You are getting mixed up. The link you have in your question is for Windows Terminal

Comment: @Paolo See the section titled "Set up Powerline in PowerShell". I edited the question to make that clearer.

Comment: *settings.json* is only mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-settings and again, as you can see, it talks about Windows Terminal

Comment: @BenHocking - the link referring to the settings file is for the windows terminal app, not for powershell. the article is quite misleadingly worded. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey It definitely omits a lot of useful details, but there is a section for powershell in the `settings.json` file for windows terminal. The two are intricately linked.

Comment: @BenHocking - to my mind, the two are not _linked_ ... one - the windows terminal - has a settings file and that settings file has a section where PoSh settings can be placed. ///// we appear to think of it rather differently. [*grin*]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the location of the `settings.json` file with the following Powershell commands:

```
$settings = (Get-Item "C:\users\$env:UserName\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_*\LocalState\settings.json")
$settings.DirectoryName
```

---

To open it from the Windows Terminal directly:

1. `Ctrl + ,`
2. Edit the `settings.json` file.
3. Save `settings.json` file.

Comment: I would assume that `$Env:LocalAppData` would look like a more streamlined solution than `C:\Users\$Env:UserName\AppData\Local`. i.e . one line `(Get-Item "$Env:LocalAppData\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_*\LocalState\settings.json").DirectoryName`.

Comment: `Ctrl + ','` has no effect on my Windows 10 :-(

Comment: @AntonioSesto did you run it from inside Windows terminal?

Comment: @Paolo no, you are right: in WIndows Terminal it does what suggested here: thanks!